# Can we initialize a pointer variable manually except 0? what is reason if can't initialize

Tags: c, pointers

Why can't we initialize a pointer variable with user defined input?

Comment: Of course you can initialize a pointer to any value. Why couldn't you? Have you had problems doing this?

Comment: How do you think a debugger do it? You can move the current position of PC, you can change registers, memory, etc. Sounds like all of those do or can represent pointers...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can initialize a pointer at the global scope to any value which is either a constant expression, or resolvable by the linker. This is because the C compiler places constants direct into the initialization code. Referenced symbols are also placed into the initialization code, and the linker replaces those symbols by the real address values.

```
// global scope
int foo;
int* bar = &foo; // ok, since &foo is a known address
int* bar2 = &foo+1; /* ok, since &foo is a known
            address and the offset is constant. */
int* whatever = (int*) 0xabcd; /* Ok, since 0xabcd is
                a constant value, and can be used as
                an address, but it depends on your
                environment if this address makes any
                sense */
int *baz = bar; /* not OK, since the value of bar is
                   stored into the RAM at run time,
                   and the linker can't determine that
                   this value does point to &foo */
```

In a function you can initialize any non-static pointer variable to a value which is already there. This is because these initializations work like normal variable assignments.

**Edit: The illegal `int *baz = bar;` part**

*Disclaimer: I describe the behavior of typical compiler+linker toolchains seen on windows, Linux and *BSD, in the embedded world the initalization can look very different.*

All initializations of variables on the global level are put into an own data segment in the executable file, and are copied at the program start into the RAM. This means that the linker must create this sections by collecting all global variables, and resolving symbol references in this section. The linker can only resolve values which contain link-time constant values only, which are addresses and numeric constants. The `int *baz = bar;` statement does use an indirect value, `bar`. While bar can be resolved to `&foo` in this specific case, the compiler does not care, since the standard requires that this is an assignment  of`baz` with the runtime memory content of bar. And since such runtime memory references are not available to the linker, since the linker can't run the program, the compiler reject to generate code for this statement.

Also changing the type of `bar` from `int* bar` to `int* const bar` does not help, because also a constant does have a memory region, and the C compiler must act as if it uses this memory region when the values is used somewhere. This means that even when it is clear which value `bar` does have, the compiler can't place the constant value into object code, since the standard requires that the runtime memory is used to determine the value of `bar` when it is used.

As a side note, in C++ it is permitted to do initializations which are based on runtime data.

Comment: why not `int *baz = bar`? bar is just a `int *`, and assigning an `int *` to another `int *` is ok; they will point both to foo.

Comment: @ShinTakezou, haven't you ever accidentally tried to initialize a global from the value of another global? It won't compile, even with non-pointers. The `gcc` error: `f.c:11: error: initializer element is not constant`. (+1, btw, excellent answer assuming the OP means "initialize in global scope".)

Comment: @ShinTakezou I updated my answer. I hope it helps, but this is one of the many parts of C where the statement `you can only learn C if you already know C` comes from.

Comment: @senderle oh yes, of course, I know the issue, just missed the `// global scope` comment and was attracted by the `not OK` on the side of something that seemed otherwise OK. Though, it is a limit imposed by the standard (moreover in this specific case a "smart" compiler could be programmed to "notice" that bar value is just &foo, i.e. a known constant value, and so baz will be too); as said it is just avoided by the standards, not a technical limit that can't be bypassed, and in fact C++ allows it.

Comment: @Rudi I was interrupted while writing the comment, then finished it and posted, just to read later you have updated the answers specifying both the things I address in the comment ("constant propagation" and limit given by the standard)

Answer (score 3):

You can initialize a pointer variable to anyvalue.

```
int *ptr = 0;
```

Initializes a pointer `ptr` to 0 (which practically means it is not pointing to anything valid)

```
int a = 10;
int *ptr = &a;
```

Initializes a pointer `ptr` to point to address of an integer variable `a`.

Comment: @RocketR: No sweat :) Hard or simple are pretty much relative terms though. Something maybe incredible simple for all and yet hard for one and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

Let me guess, you are trying to do something like this:

```
char* usersInput;
scanf("%s", usersInput);     /* error */
```

That does not work, because the string has not been allocated. You could e.g. choose what might be the maximum input-length and do:

```
char* usersInput = malloc(10000);
scanf("%s", usersInput);     /* fine */
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it, e.g.

```
uint16_t *p = 0x00DFF01C;
```

can be meaningful, **iff** it is meaningful to access that address, e.g. that address is mapped to something (e.g. a particular device) in a particular hardware. Usually it is not meaningful, save if you are writing a lowlevel code, or code for embedded systems or such.

(Or doing metal-bashing on an Amiga "classical" hardware in C)

Comment: btw I've modified the address to be the Amiga [INTENAR read only hardware register](http://amiga-dev.wikidot.com/hardware:intenar)